# Jhipster control center not showing applications

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I just created a fresh Jhipster 7.0.1 project and I'm trying to use the Jhipster Control center.

In the [official page](https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-control-center/), it says:

> As soon as an application registers on a server (consul or eureka), it
> will become available in the list.

I just started all my microservices, they are all registered in the Jhipster registry but they are still not showing up on the Control center.

Am I forgetting to do something? I didn't do any extra configuration, just created the project and started.

Comment: Do you see the Control Center in the registry? Is it configured as an eureka client of the registry?

Comment: Hello @GaëlMarziou I don't see the Control center in the registry. I used the docker-compose file inside the jhipster docker's folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use JHipster Control Center, you must edit `src/main/docker/jhipster-control-center.yml` to configure it to use your chosen discovery service (in your case Eureka with the JHipster registry).

The instructions are in the `jhipster-control-center.yml` file comments, you got to set 2 environment variables in `jhipster-control-center.yml` and remove "127.0.0.1:" prefix from `ports` in the `jhipster-registry.yml` file.